# Re-position text with Image Re-size in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, position

I've been working on this for hours, and reading over 20 articles and I still have no idea how to do this. I have a background, in which I want text to be positioned in a certain place.  Everything is fine until I view it on a monitor with a larger resolution. The background re-sizes fine, but the text is no longer in the place I want it to be.

These images hopefully will clearly describe my situation.

How I want the text to look at any resolution (this is on a 1440 x 900 monitor) http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9134840/demo/1.PNG

This is how it looks on a 1080p Monitor:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9134840/demo/2.PNG

```
 <body>
  <div id="blah">
<p id="pr">This is a paragraph!</p>
</div>
  </body>
</html>


body {background-image:url(back.jpg); background-size:cover;}
#blah{font-size:large; left:300px; top:200px; position:absolute;}
```

edit: I tried both suggestions, using divs and positioning the text absolutely and relatively and still a no go, the text still moves.

```
#contain{
position:relative;
width:7000px;
margin:0 auto;}


#blah{font-size:large; left:100px; top:200px; position:absolute;}
```

I'm not looking for a fixed positioning, because I'm going to be adding content so I need to scroll vertically through the page without the text moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out myself, big thanks to yisela for the guidance. Ultimately though, here's what I did. I looked at a site, like yahoo.com and saw that they had everything centered and had a white background. So no matter what resolution you had, it will still look neat.  With that in mind, I made sure my image was gray, and change the background to gray so it all blended in.

Now, as for the container stuff.  I placed the image in a container by itself, and centered it. Then I just set the paragraph relative to the container. That way the text will stay in the same position.

```
html{  background-color:gray }
```

body{ }

```
#contain{
width:1280px;
height:2000px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-size:cover;
background: url(back6.png); 
}

#blah{font-size:large; left:120px; top:230px; position:relative;}



<div id="blah">

<p id="pr">This is a paragraph!</p>




</div>



</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And now..I think I'll happily go back to c#, after this wonderful experience with CSS.

Comment: Glad you found a solution! You can now accept your own answer so people know which one to look at.

Answer (score 2):

Your #blah div needs to be positioned inside a relative div. You might have problems with that if you absolutely positioning something in relation to the body. Place it inside another div or use fixed positioning.

```
#containerDiv {position:relative;}
#blah {position: absolute; top:200px; left:300px;}

<div id="containerDiv "><div id="blah"></div></div>
```

Or

```
#blah {position: fixed; top:200px; left:300px;}
```

In this case your div will always remain the same place if you resize the window. If you want it to be centered, use something like:

```
#containerDiv {position:relative; width:700px; margin:0 auto;}
#blah {position: absolute; top:200px; left:300px;}
```

Also bare in mind that  background-size:cover; will not work in versions of IE.

Examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/mYcXX/1/ (absolute) vs http://jsfiddle.net/mYcXX/2/ (fixed)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I took for verbatim what you typed, and it still didn't work, perhaps I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: What I wrote is just the idea, not the final code. I'd suggest you take a look at css positions to fully understand how they work (it's not difficult, but it's quite specific)

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to do that right now. Thanks though. This is more of a headache than c# sometimes...smh.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/mYcXX/1/ and resize the little window. Now check this other one: http://jsfiddle.net/mYcXX/2/ If you change #insider to position:fixed, the position related to the window instead of the container div

Comment: Thanks, I just checked those out along with some tutorials from the w3school website. Okay, so I understand now the difference between the positions, but I'm still confused. Let's say I have a relative position form my banner, 5px, how large 5px is, is going to vary going from one resolution to another.

Comment: The size (as in how big you see it) will vary, but the whole page will do it proportionately. You will however have more problematic differences if you are trying to center something using fixed positions. Not sure I follow...

Comment: Thanks, for all the help, but I finally figured out a solution, that works. :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like fixed layout. 
If so why just not cut the central part of the background and put it in a div with style:

```
{
  width:960px; // maybe more or less - the width of the central image 
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto
}
```

And position the paragraph relating to that container (the div)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it, but it still didn't work, maybe I'm still doing something wrong? I added what I did in the edits.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can solve this problem by separating the background image style from your container.  I could be wrong, but try something like this...

```
body{
  background: url(black.png) top center no-repeat;
}

#container{
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I would recommend relying on the natural flow of **[the dom](http://www.w3.org/DOM/)** as much as possible.  Basically, don't ever rely on `position: absolute` unless ABSOLUTELY necessary.  And even then its probably a hack.